# ConTeXt : show icon on frame corner

Tags: context, framed

I am trying ConTeXt, and there is something I used to do in LaTeX that I am trying to reproduce : I used to define blocks with an icon superimposed on the top-left corner, such as in the following picture :

[image]

(I am willing to add a bottom line to change, so don't be suprised if it appears in the next examples).

While watching the manual, I finally tried to use a description environment. However, if I use the text option to contain the icon, I don't find how to place it. Here's a MWE

```
%% test 
\usemodule[ipsum]

%% Charging the icon
\usesymbols[mvs]
\definesymbol[info][{\symbol[martinvogel 2][Info]}]

%% first test
\definedescription[remark]
              [text={\tfb\symbol[info]},
                before=
                  {\startframedtext[topframe=off,rightframe=off,
                   width=broad,background=rmk,align=left]},
                after={\stopframedtext},
                location=inmargin,
                width=fit,
                title=no]

%% document
\starttext
\startremark
  \ipsum[alternative=paragraph, n=2, language=la]
\stopremark
\stoptext
```

I have looked at overlays, but I really can't seem to achieve what I'm trying to do. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your text in a `framedtext` environment and draw the rule and the symbol as a background graphic with `MetaPost`.

```
\usesymbols[mvs]

\startuseMPgraphic{information}
    draw textext.top("\tfb\symbol[martinvogel 2][Info]") shifted (-EmWidth,OverlayHeight-StrutHeight) ;
    draw leftboundary OverlayBox topenlarged -StrutHeight shifted (-EmWidth,0) ;
    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[information][\useMPgraphic{information}]

\defineframedtext
  [information]
  [frame=off,
   rulethickness=0pt,
   offset=0pt
   background=information,
   width=max]

\starttext

\startinformation
\input knuth
\stopinformation

\stoptext
```

[image: Background graphic for framed text environment]